# How to execute *.pyc file directly in linux terminal

Tags: python, linux

I found that on my ubuntu15.10, I can not execute a *.pyc file like

```
$ echo 'print "Hello"' > print.py
$ chmod +x print.py
$ python -c 'import print'
$ ./print.pyc
```

But on another PC (ubuntu15.10 too), it can be executed. In this link( 
https://superuser.com/questions/73615/how-do-pyc-files-execute/73649#73649), I know that it was because my system has not a binfmt_misc entry for .pyc files. So my question is how to add it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what distro of Linux you have. For all except Debian based distros, this should work to install the necessary files:

```
import imp,sys,string
magic = string.join(["\\x%.2x" % ord(c) for c in imp.get_magic()],"") 
reg = ':pyc:M::%s::%s:' % (magic, sys.executable) 
open("/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/register","wb").write(reg)
```

For Debian, you can install the necessary packages by installing `binfmt-support`.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21825910/shebang-for-compiled-python-code)

Best of luck, and happy coding!

Comment: @ZHAOPengyu No problem! If the solution is correct, please remember to mark it as such for future programmers.